# Arcane Hierophant and Familiars

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, familiars

The Arcane Hierophant Companion Familiar class feature says:

> Companion Familiar: Upon becoming an arcane hierophant, you must dismiss your familiar, if you have one (You do not risk losing XP for doing so.) [...]

This is puzzling to me because it seems that you just dismiss your familiar but you do not lose your ability to summon a new familiar (after a year of waiting), also it looks like your companion familiar is considered your animal companion while your familiar "slot" (let's call it so) is free, considering that it's a companion familiar with some (but not all) of the familiar features.

On top of that, should i enter the PrC from an arcane spellcasting class that doesn't have a familiar (say, a bard) and then i get one Sorcerer level then i get a familiar. The same should be true if I get Obtain Familiar (without getting sorc/wiz levels).

Common sense would dictate that once you get your companion familiar you actually lose your ability to summon other familiars but according to the class feature description you just dismiss it which is puzzling to me.

So, my question is if my reasoning is correct and i can actually get a new familiar a year later i dismissed my old one

Comment: I added the rules as written tag because this question seems to be specifically about the rules text used, as opposed to “common sense.” That’s what the tag is for, and it seems to apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### RAW

### Yup, you're right.

While it is imperative that you dismiss your familiar, nothing explicitly says that you can't summon another later, but I do think that it is a stretch of reality. As a DM I would never allow it, but it is up to you and your DM if you want to see it that way and the consequences of doing so.

#### IMHO

### Not really.

Your *animal companion* becomes your *companion familiar* by occupying the "slot" of a familiar.

> In addition, your animal companion (if any) gains many of the abilities that a familiar would normally possess. You add your arcane hierophant class level to your arcane spellcasting class level, and determine the Intelligence bonus and special abilities of your animal companion accordingly.

As you can see, the companion familiar ability is the fusion of the animal companion ability and familiar ability, your animal companion even becomes a magical beast and it seems to be (not really sure) subject to spells that target a familiar. I would say that your summon familiar ability is basically gone at this point since the class says you must dismiss it and merge the two.

Comment: @KRyan I saw something about years ago but can't find it now, then I changed it to my own opinion followed by RAW.

Comment: You actually saw dev commentary on arcane hierophant? Neat; be nice to find it. I’m kind of shocked, though; Wizards of the Coast wasn’t the most communicative in that era.

Comment: @KRyan At the time I had a player that searched this for his own character. I got some answers from them to a few topics, but usually took a month or more to get an answer.

Comment: Definitely add that if you can find it, that’s excellent. Honestly, I’d even take your word for it, if you wanted to add your recollection of that conversation to the answer. Mostly we just want to avoid people labeling their own personal opinion as RAI. Even just asserting the existence of an actual statement by them avoids a lot of problems.

Comment: @KRyan I don't have it, otherwise I would put it here. If it still exists it is on my player's email, but I lost contact lately so I'll stick as my own opinion for now. I'll be sure to present an official statement before writting RAI again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer up to now, it would be nice to have this dev commentary should you find it. I tried searching about this topic few times before asking this question but i couldn't find anything